# Habilitar comentarios en custom post type

Tags: wordpress

Tengo un custom post type llamado **"noticias"** y estoy tratando de incluirle comentarios, y no lo consigo.

Les indicaré todo lo que he hecho y nada ha funcionado:

incluir en **functions.php**

```
function default_comments_off( $data, $postarr ) {
     if( $data['post_type'] == 'page' || $data['post_type'] == 'noticias' ) {
          //New posts don't have an ID - So this checks if the post is new or already exists
          if( !($postarr['ID']) ){
               $data['comment_status'] = 1; //0 = false | 1 = true
          }
     }
     return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'default_comments_off', '', 2);
```

Al crear el custom post type, incluir en **support** los comentarios

```
function noticias(){
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Noticias',
        'singular_name' => 'Noticia',
        'add_new' => 'Agregar nueva noticia',
        'all_items' => 'Todas las noticias',
        'add_new_item' => 'Agregar nueva noticia',
        'edit_item' => 'Editar',
        'new_item' => 'Agregar nueva noticia',
        'view item' => 'Ver',
        'search_item' => 'Buscar',
        'not_found' => 'Noticia no encontrada',
        'not_found_in_trah' => 'Noticia no encontrada en la papelera'
        );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'thumbnail',
            'editor',
            'author',
            'comments'),
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'menu_name' => 'Noticias',
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-aside',
        'can_export' => true
        );
    register_post_type('noticias', $args);
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'noticias');
```

En **ajustes > comentarios**, deshabilitar la opcion "Permitir comentarios en las nuevas entradas", guardar, volverla a habilitar, volver a guardar.

Comment: Lo conseguiste al final? estoy en tu misma situación

Answer (score 0):

Hay tres  situaciones, en la arquitectura de tu plantilla , incluiste  wp-includes/comment-template.php?

======

has probado con los diferentes hooks, de comentarios de la documentación ?

```
do_action( 'comment_form', int $post_id );
```

====

la ultima, en tu código, de inicio **(estas desactivando)**  los comentarios por default, por eso no son visibles ..

```
function **default_comments_off**( $data, $postarr ) {
     if( $data['post_type'] == 'page' || $data['post_type'] == 'noticias' ) {
          //New posts don't have an ID - So this checks if the post is new or already exists
          if( !($postarr['ID']) ){
               $data['comment_status'] = 1; //0 = false | 1 = true
          }
     }
     return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'default_comments_off', '', 2);
```

te Dejo link de la documentación :

[Doc Wordpress - comment_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/)